# What to do with (possibly incorrect) revision rollbacks

Tags: discussion

I did a bit of [touch-up on a question](https://superuser.com/posts/1737263/revisions), which made it - in my view - a little bit more readable. However, the OP decided to revert it. I would appreciate a little feedback if my correction were actually out of place (I don't think so, but I'm not a native speaker). Should I "rollback" the "rollback" or just leave it as it is or do s.th. else?

Comment: In the first instance, talk to OP. Explain that you are trying to help with clarity. Of your edits the only one I can see as necessary is "whats" to "what's" which even then would be better as "what is" from my personal perspective. Unless you are fixing something actually important then rolling back should be a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mainly I wanted to correct the first sentence which doesn't seem correct and to me a little hard to read/understand: `[snip] however it is actually mounted inside the computer attached a motherboard USB C header`. My other corrections are just minor typos / grammatical errors I wanted to correct since corrections should be as complete as possible. How should I contact the OP in this case? Via the comments?

Comment: @Albin Yes, the comment section would be the appropriate place.